# Given $p\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, prove that there exists $q\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is the following:

Suppose that $q\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, prove that there exists $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
$$
q(x) = (x^2 - 3x)p''(x) + (2x-3)p'(x) + p(0).
$$
I know I can solve this by assuming that $p(x) = b_kx^k + \cdots + b_0$ and substituting it into the equation to find out the values of $b_0,\dots, b_k$, but I feel that there is an easier way, especially when $(x^2-3x)' = 2x-3$.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Your observation is a good one; by the product rule we have $(x^2 - 3x) p''(x) + (2x - 3) p'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \left( (x^2 - 3x) p'(x) \right)$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What I got is $q(x) = \frac{d}{dx} ((x^2 - 3x)p'(x) + p(0)x)$. Since the differentiation map is surjective, it's sufficient to prove that there exists $p$ such that $q_1(x) = (x^2 - 3x)p'(x) + p(0)x$ for some $q_1(x)$, i.e. $(x - 3)p'(x) + p(0) = q_2(x)$ for some $q_2(x)$, but I still need to calculate what $p$ is for a given polynomial $q_2(x)$... Now that it is reduced to a simpler problem (glad), but I feel like there should be an intuitive explanation of why there must exist $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that the equation holds.

Comment: You get that $(x^2 - 3x) p'(x) = \int_0^x (q(x) - p(0)) \, dx + C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. So you have free control over two constants on the RHS, $p(0)$ and $C$, and the question is basically: can you always select these two constants such that the RHS is divisible by $x^2 - 3x$?

Comment: Thank you! It seems that this is the intuitive explanation? I need to review some calculus knowledge but thank you for your response.

Comment: Maybe there's a simpler way but this is what pops out of using the product rule here, at least.